# Adapt layout to Android platform or API level

Tags: android, android-layout

For the application I am currently developing, I need to adapt the layout of the different activities to the user's Android API level.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is show a different layout depending on which API version is available on the device, you want to use [configuration qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers). The specifics for [alternative resources](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) are also documented.

The most basic way to do it is to create a layout folder for each API level you want to use, formatted as follows:

```
res/layout/mylayout.xml       (Default)
res/layout-v4/mylayout.xml    (Android 1.6)
res/layout-v11/mylayout.xml   (Android 3.0)
```

and so on, where `vN` is the API level. The specific API levels can be found [on this page](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/appendix/api-levels.html).

Comment: If I only had the three files described above, but I use a GB Device, which file will it use? (layout-v4 or layout)? Do I have to create a different folder for every platform? I plan to support from GB onwards

Comment: @FredericYesidPeñaSánchez It will fall backwards to the next most-matching layout. So res/layout will always be matched last, making it required, but any other is optional. You don't need a folder for every platform unless you need something to be different on each.

Comment: The links are now dead. The second one is probably this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Answer (score 6):

As Andrew Koester said you can use the different version folders, but I found this to be a lot of work because it would not fall back to the default layout. If you used layout-v14, it will work,but any api after 14 will also have this layout and you must use another layout-v? to override it again. It all depends on what your doing, but I found if your doing a lot of stuff programmatically this works wonders:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1){
            //ex. if ics is met then do this

        }else{
            //if api is not ics then do this
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have drawable resources for each of the platform level, you can use the information provided in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

More specifically, look at the 'Platform Version (API Level)' row in Table 2.