# Grid Layout & API Level

Tags: android, api, grid-layout

I want to use Grid Layout, but get the following error:

> Error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'columnCount' in package 'android'

Is this because my API level is **9**?

Does Grid Layout REALLY need API level **14**?
(I use Version: 8.0.1.v201012062107-82219)

- If yes, what should I do? Please explain this step by step.
- If no, so what's the reason? I'm doing *exactly* the same as the example!

Comment: Have a look at this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html#getColumnCount%28%29
It says API 14.

Comment: This is API Level 14 according to the docs yes. You either need to increase your min-target-SDK. Or use another approach. It could potentially work with the google compatibility thing.

Comment: could you please guide me how to increase my min-target-SDK? because i don't want use another approach..

Comment: thanks viperbone & Doomsknight, But i CAN'T visit [link](http://developer.android.com). because we're boycotted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps i spent to solve my problem:

To use GridLayout, i figured out many things should be upgraded.

1. i had "jdk 7" installed on my system, so didn't need to upgrade it.
2. i downloaded "installer_r20-windows.exe" and ran it.
3. i downloaded "platforms" which contains "android-14", and copied it into android-sdk folder. (mine is: C:\ Android\android-sdk)
4. i downloaded "system images" which contains "armeabi-v7a", and copied it into my sdk folder.
5. i downloaded "platform-tools_r13-windows" and copied it into SDK folder.
6. Then i found out also my eclipse is old, thus downloaded it's latest version, "eclipse 4.2_juno" (27 june 2012)
7. i downloaded "Eclipse-plugins-ADT-20.0.zip". Then into eclipse: Help > Install New Software > Add > Archive > Eclipse-plugins-ADT-20.0.zip. Then select "Developer Tools" > click next > accept > click finish > restart eclipse.
8. Again in eclipse: Window> Preferences > Android > SDK Location: path where my android-sdk folder exists.(e.g. mine is "C:\Android\android-sdk") > Apply > select "Android 4.0" > click OK.
9. Then i created new AVD, from: eclipse > Window > AVD Manager > New..
10. Finally, into sdk folder i created a new folder named "extras", into it another new folder named "android", into it another new folder named "support".
11. Then i extracted content of "support_r09.zip" (which have downloaded it).

Now everything is ok..

Thanks to everybody helped me in this post (viperbone, Doomsknight, Matthieu, MemLeak,Jeroen).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the GridLayout is only available if you run it on devices with API Level 14 or higher.

Not sure what that version 8.0.1.... is ? Definitely not the Android version.

If you plan to run your application on anything earlier than Ice Cream Sandwich I am afraid you have to use something else than that Layout. TableLayout maybe ? Or check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126780/how-to-make-android-gridlayout-compatible-to-older-version)

MORE (from comments):

Either you are ok with your app to run only on ICS or above (so somebody with a phone with Gingerbread will not be able to run it for example).

If yes, then:

- Download the latest Android SDK
- Set targetSDKversion="14" in your manifest

And this error should go away.

If no, then you CANNOT use GridLayout. You have a few options to replace it:

- Download the library from : https://github.com/dlew/android-gridlayout and use that
- Use some other layout (like TableLayout or LinearLayouts)

Comment: Hi Matthieu. OK, to be more clear i use Android 2.3 (API level:9).

Comment: Then either you use that custom library that is linked from github or you have to use something else (TableLayout, construction of LinearLayouts...)

Comment: And i'm writing a game program "on my LAPTOP" using emulator. PLEASE TELL me what should i do? Is there anyway to upgrade?

Comment: What do you mean? " you use that custom library that is linked from github"??

Comment: the question is really what you want to app to run on... if it's ok to run only on ICS, then make sure you download the latest SDK and change your AndroidManifest to have targetSDKversion="14" then you are able to use the GridLayout

Comment: i HAVE TO use grid layout. do you have any sample of it?

Comment: i've added <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" in my manifest. Isn't that sufficient?

Comment: Make sure you have the latest SDK installed on your computer too

Comment: Matthieu, did you know that there is a package called support-library-v7? This one will provide the GridLayout to older API Levels.

Comment: @DerGolem I did not know that... maybe I missed it or it was not available when I wrote this.

Answer (score 1):

GridLayout needs [API 14](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html)

You can create a Layout for the other android versions -> [Adapt layout to Android platform or API level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536079/adapt-layout-to-android-platform-or-api-level)

Comment: Can you guide me how to get API 14?

Comment: look [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html) or if installed change the target in the manifest.xml

Comment: Of course, please another way than "developer.android.com". Because our country is FORBIDEN. HELP ME, PLEASE.

Comment: _On Windows, double-click the SDK Manager.exe file at the root of the Android SDK directory._

Comment: Hi MemLeak. would you please ANSWER me..?

Comment: OK, i did it. nothing special appeared.(i see choose packages to install. but it is EMPTY!). and then?

Comment: Now you can change your settings in manifest.xml (to api 14) <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />

Comment: You can use the support library v7, which includes the GridLayout

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest use:

```
<uses-sdk minSdkVersion="14" />
```

However, this will mean that any device running an `Android API` below **14** will not be able to use your app

Comment: You can use the support library v7, which includes the GridLayout