# android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout cannot get it to work

Tags: android, grid-layout, android-support-library, android-gridlayout

I have an android project which utilizes GridLayout in most of its menus and screens. The problem however is that GridLayout is supported from API 14 and onwards.

Since I want to make the application available to older version of android as well, I tried to use Android's own Support Library [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html) which adds support up to API 7. 
This was exactly what I was looking for, however I cannot for the life of me get it to work. I have tried all of these explanations and ideas:

1. [Android's official instructions](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)
2. [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18125947/475680)
3. [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12477911/475680)
4. [Solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17160246/475680)
5. [Solution 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12644746/475680)
6. [Solution 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8884893/475680)

and more...

No matter what I do, how I do it or what IDE I use (whether Eclipse ADT or Android Studio), it always gives me an error in the Layout XML along the lines of:

```
The following classes could be instantiated:  - android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout

With either one of these exceptions showing in the error log:

1. android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not resolve value 0x7F080000
2. java.lang.classnotfoundexception: android.support.v7.gridlayout.R$dimen
```

Edit: For reference this is what I'm using to create the support gridlayout (taken directly from the android sample programs):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/blue"
    android:padding="10dip"
    app:columnCount="4"
    >
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/string_test"
    />
    <EditText
        app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnSpan="4"
    />
    <Button
        android:text="@string/button_test"
        app:layout_column="2"
    />
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

What could I possibly be doing wrong that none of the above solutions work? Is there something I'm missing, maybe there's a problem with my original code?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: @nsvir - added my XML code, though nothing special about it, I used the sample code given by android

Answer (score 52):

Try using Gradle, and in your build.gradle file add the following section at the end:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

Then execute assembleDebug gradle task.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. 

Importing v24 appcompat and later in ADT (Eclipse) will not work. Build tools are not storing ADT-compatible libraries anymore, and extracting from .aar is too much work - consider moving to Android Studio and Gradle-based build system.

Comment: With Android Studio 3.0 on wards, instead of `compile` use `implementation`

Answer (score 4):

With Android Studio:

- Go in the build.gradle and add:

  ```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
  ```

  in your dependencies.
- Sync your project by clicking the icon on the left of AVD manager. It will implement the library
- And try again

With Eclipse try this: [Gridview v7 support for older api android.support.v7.widget.Gridlayout failed to instaniate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822977/gridview-v7-support-for-older-api-android-support-v7-widget-gridlayout-failed-to/17160246#17160246)

Comment: The code I'm using is running without gradle (while trying to create one via eclipse it shows an error and doesn't do anything), I saw this solution but since I'm not using gradle it's not viable

Comment: Did you restart your IDE ?

Comment: Yes, multiple times. Tried creating numerous new projects just to test but nothing works

Comment: Well I tried on Android Studio and Eclipse by importing appcompat and/or gridlayout and It doesn't work for me neither.. Sorry

Comment: Thanks anyway, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

For current stable Release 1.0.0 :
To add a dependency on GridLayout, you must add the Google Maven repository to your project.
Add the dependencies for the artifacts you need in the build.gradle file for your app or module:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: this is buggy, causing me lot of issues :\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\834d222cdf56ff4579f6f997b4d0229f\gridlayout-1.0.0\res\values\values.xml:3:5-73:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.

Answer (score 2):

Refer from http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-gridlayout, you should import gridlayout as a eclipse project, then add it as an library project into your project, make sure the build path has included the jar.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I fixed it setting:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

in the gridlayout_v7 project manifest file.