# How to use xml attributes from higher api on lower api?

Tags: android, xml, grid-layout

I want to use xml attributes from higher api on lower android system. How to do that without changing much? like `android:layout_columnWeight` and `android:layout_rowWeigh`.
Here is my xml code:

```
<GridLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:id="@+id/hello"
    android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="How are you"
    android:id="@+id/howareyou"
    android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="good evening"
    android:id="@+id/goodevening"
    android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="please"
    android:id="@+id/please"
    android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="my name is"
    android:id="@+id/mynameis"
    android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="do you &#10;speak english"
    android:id="@+id/doyouspeakenglish"
    android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="welcome"
    android:id="@+id/welcome"
    android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="i live in"
    android:id="@+id/ilivein"
    android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>
```

please don't say to use another method to do that, gridLayout is very useful but I can't use on lower android systems.

Comment: It might be helpful to specify what API level you are targetting that is too low for GridLayout. Isn't it a v7 support library?

Comment: These attributes are not tied to an API level. These attributes are tied to the container. You can use [the attributes defined on `GridLayout.LayoutParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.LayoutParams.html) because your widgets are inside of a `GridLayout`. And, as the answers note, use the `GridLayout` backport in the `support-v4` library, if you want to use `GridLayout` prior to API Level 14.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can use [`android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html) from the Android Support Library in place of the standard `GridLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Just switch to the `GridLayout` from the support library.

That way you get to use your `layout_columnWeight` on older APIs, but replace the `android` namespace prefix with `app`.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506055/android-support-v7-widget-gridlayout-cannot-get-it-to-work)

The only other alternative is to use an alternative layout file inside your `layout-v21` directory or something.