# How to Adapt layout to multi-Android API level for using switch and toggle buttons?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two layouts one for before API level-14 and the other is for what's after. I need to use toggle button in before level-14 API and a switch button for the one after level-14.

The problem is that I want to use both with the same id in R.id.button1 or Do I have to make each one with a different id and check inside the Java code the version of API running so I find the view by id that works for the API. And if so how can I do that please provide a sample of code. **Thanks for your time**.

These are the XML files

**layout-v14**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Ordinary layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**The Java code**

```
CompoundButton button = (CompoundButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Comment: Related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536079/adapt-layout-to-android-platform-or-api-level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of them extends CompoundButton, so you can use the same ID, but if you want the same code, you have to limit your useness to CompoundButton class.

**Edit**

```
CompoundButton button = (CompoundButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setChecked(checked);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Build.VERSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) for getting the api-level Programmatically.

**Edit**

```
if(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH == Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
    ((Switch)v).switchMethodSpecefic();
```

Comment: This won't work if you use a minimum SDK version less than the one added the switch in this case is level-14.